# Can Wordpress automatic update harm my website?

Tags: wordpress

Recently I got to know that my Wordpress site is automatically updating itself when a new version of Wordpress is available. I know that this automatic feature is available in

Wordpress since sometimes back. But I have some questions about this

1) Can this be risky in any case?
2) Doesn't it a matter the way how we have installed Wordpress? (e.g plugins and security settings)
3) Does Wordpress have a way to recover our website if anything happen?
4) Don't they keep any backup before do the update?

Could you please give me your answers to the above?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). it is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer each of your questions to the best of my knowledge:

**1) Can this be risky in any case?**
The automatic updates are mostly security updates. Though you can never be 100% sure it doesn't break anything, security updates don't deprecate functions or change much on how the CMS works. This means that nearly every plugin and theme can still use the same functions without issue.

**2) Doesn't it a matter the way how we have installed Wordpress? (e.g plugins and security settings)**
This ofcourse matters, to some extend. But if a site is working in Wordpress 3.8.3, it will still work in Wordpress 3.8.4. If a site however uses functions that will be deprecated, you might have problems when upgrading from 3.8 to 3.9. However, major updates aren't done automatically, and still need to be done manually, giving you the opportunity to make a backup beforehand.

**3) Does Wordpress have a way to recover our website if anything happen?**
No, it doesn't. You CAN however turn of the automatic updates. But, as stated at question 1, the risks aren't very big with the security updates.

**4) Don't they keep any backup before do the update?**
No they don't. It is your own responsibility to keep backups of your website.

I hope this answers your questions. If something is unclear, please let me know in the comments, and I'll look into it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your themes and plugins use functions from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) then I think your are much safer. Make sure the plugins and themes are using functions to get directories and URI's through functions defined by Codex, what I mean to say is:
use: get_template_directory_uri();
instead of `xyz.com/wp-content/themes` or even `home_url('/wp-content/themes');` and other things like that.

Answer (score 0):

yes sometime it can create a mess and it won't allow to admin to login.

most command questions asked are
Can't login after automatic update
login failed after wordpress update.

here is a very quick fix for all of them.
http://onl9class.com/solved-cant-login-after-wordpress-update/

Answer (score 0):

Here is all answer of your questions, please check below:

**1. Can this be risky in any case?** 
The automatic updates are good for security purpose but some times it will break our function work in website because some plugin developer will not update own code according to wp updates so it would be good you can manually updates all things after checking plug-ins compatibility with new version.

**2. Doesn't it a matter the way how we have installed Wordpress?** 
No it always matter, because some times wordpress core developer changes the function and they will be depreciate in new version so it would be good, always take backup of website and manually do the updates.

**3. Does Wordpress have a way to recover our website if anything happen?**
 No, but you can install wp plugin and schedule it to take backup in each week.so you can at-least get the latest backup of website. I always use the back up plugin in my websites.

**4. Don't they keep any backup before do the update?** 
No they don't take backup of website. but wp always show notification when you start update please take backup.

Thanks